# Could not find or load main class in Client-Server programming

Tags: sockets

I am trying to run Client code in Clinet-Server programming in java and I am getting error "**Could not find or load main class.**"

`javac DateClient.java`

`java DateClient` (I have also tried "java -cp . DateClient" but still not working).

Program which I am trying to run is :

```
package edu.lmu.cs.networking;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DateClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String serverAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(

        "Enter IP Address of a machine that is\n" +

        "running the date service on port 9090:");

        Socket s = new Socket(serverAddress, 9090);

        BufferedReader input =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

        String answer = input.readLine();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, answer);

        System.exit(0);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is in the package `edu.lmu.cs.networking`. Its name is thus `edu.lmu.cs.networking.DateClient`. And you thus need to execute it with

```
java -cp . edu.lmu.cs.networking.DateClient
```

(assuming `.` contains the `edu` directory, which contains the `lmu` directory, which contains the `cs` directory, which contains the `networking` directory, which contains the file `DateClient.class`).